# How can I initialize my Matrix object as I would do with a multidimensional array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, neural-network

I had to create a Matrix class, so I could make use of that in my Neural Network project. How could I achieve that when creating a Matrix object, it would work like it does with multidimensional array?

So basically I have a Matrix class which looks like this:

```
class Matrix
{
    private int rows;
    private int size;
    private int columns;
    private double[,] _inMatrix;
    public double this[int row, int col]
    {
        get
        {
            return _inMatrix[row, col];
        }
        set
        {
            _inMatrix[row, col] = value;
        }

    }
    public Matrix(int row, int col)
    {
        rows = row;
        columns = col;
        size = row * col;
        _inMatrix = new double[rows, columns];
    }
    public Matrix()
    {

    }
    //and bunch of operations
```

It works like a charm when I know the rows and columns of the Matrix, but I would love to be able to set the values at the start or later.
When I create a Matrix object, I do it this way:

```
Matrix m1=new Matrix(row, column)
```

What I want to do is to be able to set the values at the start like I would with arrays.
I know that in C# this is how we initialize a multidimensional array:

```
double[,] 2Darray = new double[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
//or
int[,] 2Darray;
2Darray = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

How could I achieve something similar?

Comment: Try changing `_inMatrix = new double[rows, columns];` to `_inMatrix = new double[,] { };`

Comment: You could easily pass an array into your constructor and create your matrix object in that way.

Comment: Read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this, to have `implicit operator` to be able to do `Matrix m = new double[,] { {1,1}, {2,3}};`. Also you don't need `_rows` and `_columns` as you could easily extract that from the underlaying multidimensional array(`GetLength(int dimention)`).

```
class Matrix
{
    private double[,] _inMatrix;

    public double this[int row, int col]
    {
        get => _inMatrix[row, col];
        set => _inMatrix[row, col] = value;
    }

    public Matrix(double[,] a) => Initialize(a);

    //and bunch of operations

    private void Initialize(double[,] a) => _inMatrix = a;

    public static implicit operator Matrix(double[,] a) => new Matrix(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the values beforehand you can just do what you already suggest yourself.

Just fill your empty constructor with the values u want there.

```
public Matrix()
{
    _inMatrix = new double[ , ] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
}
```

After that you can just create the new matrix with the values u wanted to be there.

```
Matrix m1=new Matrix()
```

You can even create a matrix where you want your matrix to be initialized and pass it into another constructor.

```
public Matrix(double[,] _NewMatrix)
{
    _inMatrix = _NewMatrix;
}
```

and call it with

```
double[,] NewMatrix = new double[ , ] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
Matrix m_Matrix = new Matrix( NewMatrix );
```